Slam stem without increasing reach

(mm=cm)
I want to slam the stem and switch to a -17 degree stem for aesthetics. I know that I can comfortably ride with the corresponding stack height because my old bike has a much lower stack height. With the new bike I would love to get rid of that spacer tower. But if I slam it with the same stem length, my reach increases. If I switch to a 8cm stem in this case, would it alter the handling much? I mean, the handlebars should be in the same position, just a few centimeters lower…

It won't alter the handling much. 80-90-100mm all feel quite similar on the same bike. For bike fitting purposes, a change at the bars must be 10mm+ for the rider to really notice.

@Vorac how does a road or MTB context clarify or change the nature of the question?

If we're talking stems of 80-100mm, this would seem to rule out modern MTBs.

@PaulH jumping cliffs differs from riding tarmac as efficiently as possible. On a "race" bike I would advise OP to sink down the hoods and feel it. On an MTB I would have an awful lot of questions.

@Vorac I see all of that as orthogonal to the question of geometry and handling. In any case, it’s better to slam the stem for aggressive MTB riding to minimize stresses on the steerer and preserve the intended reach of the frame. In such cases, you should use riser bars to raise your cockpit. Additionally, there’s a wide gulf of off-road cycling before you get to dropping off cliffs.

@PaulH ironically Your criticism underlines the necessity of my comment,

All of your comments are pretty vague, and mine wasn’t a criticism. Can you elaborate?

@PaulH basically what Nathan's answer describes.  I've ridden a hugely undersized bike. Awesome for jumps & drops. On the road basically doesn't work(kicking tires, elbows to the gut etc.). This bike had a horrible fit for me but was the best bike ever for the mentioned activities.

@Vorac I must be missing something. I don't see how Nate's answer changes between MTB and road contexts.

The entire topic of what effect stem rise and extension has on handling is one of those cycling topics where the conversation is easily riddled with hearsay and assumptions, but you could do a college physics class in how it actually works and still have more questions than answers at the other end of it.
Speaking strictly in terms of how the bike responds to inputs at the bars, all that matters is how far in front of the steering axis the bar clamp is horizontally. The amount of extension the stem has by itself is an irrelevant number. So if it lines up the way it does in a drawing like yours, the difference in that respect is going to be very little.
Where it gets fuzzier is the experience of handling the bike in the different posture you'll be in. You're going much lower and will have more weight over the front wheel. If that's the position your body wants to be in more you should still do it, but it's going to make handling the bike feel quite a bit different.
